# How to use new line character i.e. \n with iOS push notification alert title?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, newline

I want to use new line characters with my push notifications alert title.

What I'm trying to achieve is basically this:

I have an alert title "Title. Body." I want "Body." to start from a new line.
Using "Title.\nBody." doesn't work I've already tested it. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you talking about local or remote notifications?

Comment: @lev landau Remote notifications